# Java "File" works but "InputStream" does not

Tags: java, inputstream, fileinputstream

EDIT: [getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

Is the best explanation I have found. Personally after trying all the different subclasses of InputStream I feel the implementation of the InputStream returned by FileInputstream() and the one returned by getResourceAsStream() are subtly different in some way (causing an incompatibility with javax.xml.parsers.. )

I'll leave this open for a while just in case someone happens to have an answer, but I'm done. thanks for all the advice, suggestions and help. Time too move on to the next thing.

---

I've have a servlet which collects it's initialization data from an XML ini file, it opens it as an InputStream from the servlet session context like this

```
   HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
   ServletContext ctx=session.getServletContext();
   InputStream myini = ctx.getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/myini.xml");
```

That works, but later on I'm writing JUnit tests and in the setup function, and I need to access this same ini. I don't have the servlet context in the test environment so I try to create an InputStream using

```
InputStream testing = new FileInputStream(String pathToFile);
```

and also

```
InputStream testing = new FileInputStream(File fileObj);
```

The exception thrown from the XML parser (below)

I find it impossible to get an InputStream for my init file and am forced to use File.

I checked the javadoc's, moved the file location in case of security restrictions. Eventually added dual constructors to the classes needing the ini, to accept both File and InputStream to cater for unit testing (where I need the File ref)and runtime (where the InputStream is returned from the servlet session context) ...

But i'm perplexed/pretty frustrated so I have to ask

How come I can return a file object using "File", which can then be successfully parsed by the javax.xml.parsers (see function below)

```
File myini = new File("C:\\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\\myini\\myini.xml");
```

But I cannot do the same with this using "InputStream" ?

```
InputStream myini = new FileInputStream("C:\\apache-tomcat-7.0.30\\myini\\myini.xml");
```

Using the exactly the same String path (i.e. the file exists)

Respectively each gets passed to either

```
public xmlNode parse(InputStream is) throws xmlException {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = dBuilder.parse(is);
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            xmlNode node = new xmlNode(document.getDocumentElement());
            return node;
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new xmlException("Error in configuration of XML parser", e);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            throw new xmlException("Error in parsing XML document", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new xmlException("Error in reading InputStream", e);
        }
    }
```

Or

```
public xmlNode parse(File file) throws xmlException {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            document = dBuilder.parse(file);
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            xmlNode node = new xmlNode(document.getDocumentElement());
            return node;
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new xmlException("Error in configuration of XML parser", e);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            throw new xmlException("Error in parsing XML document", e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new xmlException("Error in opening file", e);
        }
    }
```

This Exception gets thrown only when the InputStream method is called (after the appropriate initialization as above)

```
xml.utils.xmlException: Error in reading InputStream
    at xml.utils.xmlDocument.parse(xmlDocument.java:40)
    at com.jcando.util.XMLini.<init>(XMLini.java:49)
```

Is there a different way of defining the path as a string for the InputStream ?
Is there a security block I'm unaware of?

If someone can explain what I am missing, or where I am being thick as a stump I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What's the error? And what do you do with your file object after creating it?

Comment: what error you are getting with `new FileInputStream` ?

Comment: No Error, just an empty/closed FileInputStream

Comment: how are you making sure that its closed?

Comment: after I create the file object it gets passed to an xml parsing class to extract initialization parameters/database connection information

Comment: How is the path different? ,that smells like the right anwser

Comment: If `File` works for you, and I'm assuming *"works"* means that you could actually read data when using `File`, have you tried `FileInputStream(File file)`, instead of `FileInputStream(String name)`?

Comment: @afsantos, yes that was one of the things I tried. I also moved the file location, from project root, onto a classpath, into a folder and used hard coded absolute String references as above

Comment: @sanbhat, I am using the debugger in eclipse to inspect it.

Comment: Can you add more code showing what you do with the `File` that works, and the `InputStream` that does not?  As well as elaborating on what "works" and "does not work" means more specifically.

Comment: @increment1, I have added the exception detail and the parsing functions which work, and don't work.

Comment: Just a small question: you are not running these two at the same time do you?

Comment: Is that the only exception or is it wrapping any other exception?  And this InputStream, it is handed off to the parse message in the same thread, not between threads at all?

Comment: @increment1 its caused by an i/o Exception, thrown by the read method of FileInputStream, there is no threading. There are bytes available, I found a good answer which I'm adding to my question, it does not resolve my question but I think its as close as Ill get, see above.

Comment: It would probably help if you posted the wrapped exception as well.

Comment: @Dolda2000, its an i/o Exception, thrown by the read method of FileInputStream. Caused by: java.io.IOException: Read error
 at java.io.FileInputStream.read(Native Method)

Comment: Yes, I figured as much, but the complete stacktrace and message just might be useful. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getResourceAsStream() vs FileInputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308188/getresourceasstream-vs-fileinputstream)

Is the best explanation I have found. Personally after trying all the different subclasses of InputStream I feel the implementation of the InputStream returned by FileInputstream() and the one returned by getResourceAsStream() are subtly different in some way (causing an incompatibility with javax.xml.parsers.. )

Answer (score 2):

You can always write `File f = new File("anyName")`: it will never throw an exception even if the file does not exist.

Yet, writing `InputStream myini = new FileInputStream("anyName")` will throw a `FileNotFoundException` exception if the file does not exist as you can see in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: The file exists, File works, InputStream does not. your not really answering my question I'm not trying to raise an exception.

Comment: Check that your file actually exists for the program using ``myini.exists();``

Comment: the file exists (as shown by the absolute path code working when using File, and no Exception being thrown by File and no FileInputStream), sorry but you are again not addressing the issue. No worries it's not an easy issue and as I said in my update above I've moved on. I have no idea why your answer was up-voted as it is completely off the mark.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you may have a character encoding error or an error related to resolving relative urls within your document (although I am not sure if that would cause an exception).

I think that you may want to look at trying something like:

```
InputSource source = new InputSource(is);
source.setEncoding(... your character encoding ...);
source.setSystemId(systemId);
dBuilder.parse(inputSource);
```

Where `systemId` is determined as `file.toURI().toASCIIString()`.